# R 3.3.2 Error importing CSV using read.table -- Probable quoting issue

Tags: r, csv, double-quotes, read.table

I have a large csv dataset that is proving to be a pain to import into R.

Below is an example of the dataset, with all of the relevat issues:

```
col 1,col 2,col 3,col 4
txt 1,txt ' 2,"This is a big

field with carriage returns, all enclosed in double

quotes",txt 4
txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4
```

So as you can see, there are problems with single quotes within fields, double quotes enclosing large blocks of texts that contain commas, and new lines within fields (all of which should be enclosed by double quotes). But fields don't have double quotes if they contain no commas and no new lines.

I've tried

```
read.table(file, sep = ",", quote = '"', header = TRUE)
```

But I receive the error

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  line 31 did not have 95 elements
```

Not sure exactly what the problem is, but I'm sure it's related to the conditional double quote text qualifiers, the new lines, or both.

Any advice on adjusting the code or how I might troubleshoot? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With fread from the data.table package, it works fine with default args:

```
DF = data.table::fread(data.table = FALSE, "col 1,col 2,col 3,col 4
txt 1,txt ' 2,\"This is a big

field with carriage returns, all enclosed in double

quotes\",txt 4
txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4")
```

giving

```
  col 1   col 2                                                                                          col 3 col 4
1 txt 1 txt ' 2 This is a big\n    \n    field with carriage returns, all enclosed in double\n    \n    quotes txt 4
2  txt1    txt2                                                                                           txt3  txt4
```

I suspect it can be done with appropriate args passed to read.table, but it's probably not worth the trouble assuming you can install data.table or some other package that handles this better.

Comment: After going over around 20 answers in multiple threads, I learned that fread is awesome

Answer (score 5):

I can do it on this toy example but I'm not at all confident this is the right way to go. My experience with real-world CSV files is that there are often other glitches that will defeat such efforts.

```
xs <- scan( what="", sep=",", quote="\"")
# then paste in your text:

1: col 1,col 2,col 3,col 4
5: txt 1,txt ' 2,"This is a big
5: 
5: field with carriage returns, all enclosed in double
5: 
5: quotes",txt 4
9: txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4
13: 
Read 12 items
```

(Upvote to Frank's data.table success.)

Since `read.table` is really a wrapper around the `scan` function I experimented with these settings and eventually understood that I would need to escape that interior single quote on the second line:

```
read.table( text='col 1,col 2,col 3,col 4
txt 1,txt \' 2,"This is a big

field with carriage returns, all enclosed in double

quotes",txt 4
txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4
', header=TRUE, sep=",", quote="\"")
```